# How to iterate through a global array and return user input

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, ajax

I am trying to build a news site using the guardian api and search this api using user input to return the webTitle attribute for each matching element. I know simply appending user input into the ajax call would be a simpler method of completing this task but I'm looking for a bit of a challenge so I decided I could assign the ajax response to a global array and iterate through that to find the user input but I am having trouble iterating through the array.

The code for the global array and ajax call is here;

```
var searchQuery=[];           

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://content.guardianapis.com/search?&api-key=xxxx',
                    async: true,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){
                        searchQuery.push(data);
                    }
                });
```

And this works as when outputted to the console it shows the array populated with all of the elements within the ajax call.

I am just wondering how I can then take this array, and using JQuery, iterate through it and check if any elements contain the user input from an input text box located in my application preferably when the search button is clicked, the code for which is here;

```
<div id="search">
                            <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                                <input type="text" class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Search" id= 'userSearch' <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="How To Search" data-content="Enter a Key Word and Receive News Stories Associated With It"></a>
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary mb1 bg-blue" type="button" id="submitSearch">
                                        <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
</div>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated and I'm sure it is just my inexperience with web development giving me the issues so please don't judge me too much haha.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$("#submitSearch").on("click", function(){
    var keyword = $("#userSearch").val();
    searchQuery.map(function(item){
        if(item.indexOf(keyword) != -1){
            //found, do something about it 
            console.log(item);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: This seems to give me the error ;                                      
        news_site.html:155 Uncaught TypeError: item.indexOf is not a function. Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Comment: Well I'm not sure the structure of the searchQuery so this is just give you some general idea. Basically your got this error because each item of the searchQuery is not a string. Perhaps they are objects?  If so you need to change the code to be something like: if(item.webTitle.indexOf(keyword) != -1)

Answer (score 0):

Going by what your require, here's something that may help you:

```
var searchQuery;
var keyword = $("#userSearch").val().toLowerCase();

$.ajax({
   url: 'https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=xxxx',
   async: true,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data){
      searchQuery =  data.response.results;
   }
});

$("#submitSearch").on("click", function(){
    for(i=0;i<searchQuery.length;i++){
       if(searchQuery[i].webTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) > 0){
         console.log(searchQuery[i].webTitle);
         console.log(searchQuery[i].webUrl);
         console.log(searchQuery[i].apiUrl);
       }
    } 
});
```